# Bolt python bot running in Azure functions

Tags: python-3.x, azure, function, slack-bolt

Currently have an Azure function(python) which responds to the challenge from the slack and triggers another function to send the message to my slack channel.
I want to listen to events(simple hello from any user) and send the message to the channel with bot ideally in threads but can be in the channel as well.
But with bolt framework it doesn't work ((

what i tried

```
import azure.functions as func
from slack_bolt import App
import json
import os

# Initializes your app with your bot token and signing secret
app = App(
    token=os.environ.get("SLACK_BOT_TOKEN"),
    signing_secret=os.environ.get("SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET")
)


# Listens to incoming messages that contain "hello"
@app.message("hello")
def message_hello(message,say):
# say() sends a message to the channel where the event was triggered
    say(f"Hey there <@{message['user']}>")


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        # checking if in req http request has a json and putting this value into req_body
        req_body = req.get_json() 

    except ValueError: 
        return func.HttpResponse("Invalid JSON in request body", status_code=400)

    request_type = req_body.get('type')# here we are getting the request type value 

    if request_type == 'url_verification': #checking if the request type is url_verification 

        challenge = req_body.get('challenge') #from request type we are getting challenge value 

        if challenge: # if challenge is has something in it

            #Responding with the challenge in JSON format 
            response_data ={"challenge":challenge} #creating a dict for storing challenge key is challenge 

            #returning the response with json format 
            return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data),status_code=200, mimetype="application/json")
            
        else:
            # Missing challenge parameter in the request
            return func.HttpResponse("Missing challenge parameter in the request", status_code=400)
        
    else:
        # Respond to other types of requests as needed
        
        return func.HttpResponse("Unhandled request type", status_code=400)
        


#start our app 
if __name__=="__main__":

     app.start(port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 3000)))
```

Comment: Can you please specify your requirement? What do you want to achieve here and what is the issue you are facing with the given code

Comment: Hi dear @IkhtesamAfrin  am not sure what do you mean by requirements ) I want to just be able to react to user message in the channel with bot

Comment: I do have an azure function in Azure Apps services with Python 3.9  and the secrets are stored there as well . I have a specific slack channel where my bot is installed with write and read and listen to events like if someone sends the message to the channel . The endpoint url is verified with challenge in slack app (bot )subscriptions

Comment: I modified the above code which is deployed to Azure Functions and runs without any errors previously i did not have  have slack bolt part just function which sends the message to the channel                                                                                               
 def sending_message_to_bek_testbot():
    client = WebClient(slack_token)
    channel_id = "#bek_testbot" #channel ID 
    result =client.chat_postMessage(channel=channel_id,text='Function is started hey') #sending message to the channel

Comment: Azure function is an HTTP trigger type